# How can I get the logged-in user's Google/Gmail profile picture?

Tags: scala, gmail-api, akka-http

I am creating an application in Scala using akka-http where I want to display the user's Gmail profile picture after they have logged in using a Gmail account.

How should I do it? I notice that Stack Overflow can do this, so there must be a way of doing so.

I have a link that requires me to enter account_id for that particular ID. How can I get this account ID?

*https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/(account_id)?personFields=names%2Cphotos&key=(api_key)*